# AutoHotKey: How to disable a Skype hotkey and make your keyboard behave normally

Tags: autohotkey, skype

Skype HotKeys are really annoying as they cannot be disabled from Skype itself. The most annoying of all was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, that started a Skype call with any of your contact if it was selected. This has been replaced recently by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

See http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Disable-CTRL-R-on-windows/td-p/2877763

Unfortunately, it happens to me that I get <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> as a mapped key to the "è" character (using microsoft keybord creator). So in all my applications, I can write happily in French with a US keyboard, using <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> for my "è" character all the time. Except in Skype, now.

Reading the link above, I created an AutoKey script, to disable Skype's hotkey:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe Skype.exe ; utilizes this script for Skype only
!^r:: ; replace [ctrl][alt][r] with nothing
#If     ; closes IfWinActive condition, needed if more code comes after this
```

But, although this disables the Skype hotkey, it prevents the normal input of my "è" character in a Skype discussion. So good, but not best, as my typing get all mangled in Skype now.

I have tried other options, but to no avail:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe Skype.exe ; utilizes this script for Skype only
!^r:: 
Send è  
return
#If     ; closes IfWinActive condition, needed if more code comes after this
```

or

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe Skype.exe ; utilizes this script for Skype only
!^r:: 
SendInput {Raw}è  
return
#If     ; closes IfWinActive condition, needed if more code comes after this
```

But as soon as !^r is not strictly disabled, then it launched a Skype call.

Anyone with more experience with AutoHotKey and/or Skype to help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that this

```
#IfWinActive, ...
!^r::
#If
```

is no valid deactivation of a hotkey: attach the `return` keyword, so it is `!^r::return`. Otherwise, after pressing alt ctrl r, any code further down below will also be executed.

Also, if you only want to remap the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> hotkey, you should use `<^>!r::` as the trigger, as suggested in the [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm). This way, the natural `alt+ctrl+r` behavior will be preserved, in this case making a call.

---

I cannot fully reproduce your issue.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe Skype.exe
<^>!r::
send a
return 
#ifWinActive
```

works perfectly fine for me and does not call my active contact in skype. `AltGr` is being overridden correctly. **But** if I change `send a` to `send è`, the script starts acting weirdly. It only works for the first time: after that, I have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> manually once in order for `è` to be sent again. This looks like a bug to me.

A workaround might be

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe Skype.exe
<^>!r::
send è
keywait, alt
send {alt}
return 
#ifWinActive
```

or

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe Skype.exe
<^>!r::
keywait, alt
send è
return 
#ifWinActive
```

. But this still does not make it possible to send multiple `è`'s while holding `altGr` down. You'll have to release `AltGr` after each `è`.

**Edit** - I found a 100% working solution:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe Skype.exe
<^>!r::
SendUnicodeChar(0x00E8)
return 
#ifWinActive

; SOURCE for the following: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/16404-inserting-unicode-special-characters/
SendUnicodeChar(charCode)
{
    VarSetCapacity(ki, 28 * 2, 0)
    EncodeInteger(&ki + 0, 1)
    EncodeInteger(&ki + 6, charCode)
    EncodeInteger(&ki + 8, 4)
    EncodeInteger(&ki +28, 1)
    EncodeInteger(&ki +34, charCode)
    EncodeInteger(&ki +36, 4|2)

    DllCall("SendInput", "UInt", 2, "UInt", &ki, "Int", 28)
}

EncodeInteger(ref, val)
{
    DllCall("ntdll\RtlFillMemoryUlong", "Uint", ref, "Uint", 4, "Uint", val)
}
```

this is the same as above, but instead of using `send è` or `send {ASC 0232}`, it uses unicode formatting.

Comment: Thanks Blauhim. I tried both your scripts, but in both case, Skype does try to make a call. :'-(
I changed my original one with your suggestion (adding return). 
I am on Skype 7.4.0.102, Win 7 64, AutHotKey 1.1.22.00 to give you full context,

Comment: Ah, on the other hand:
`#IfWinActive, ahk_exe Skype.exe
<^>!r::
send e
return
#ifWinActive`
works perfectly well. 
Yes, there is something weird with è
Well, 'e' is better than nothing. :)

Comment: Funny, I tried:
`#IfWinActive, ahk_exe Skype.exe 
<^>!r:: 
send {ASC 0232}
return 
#ifWinActive#If`
and now I reproduce your behaviour: It works once, and then the key freezes, and you need to press Alt to re-enable it.

Comment: `#IfWinActive, ahk_exe Skype.exe
<^>!r::
keywait, alt
send {ASC 0232}
return 
#ifWinActive`
is a winner: Yes, I need to release AltGr before I can write another è, but there is no word with double-è in French, so I can live with that. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Great! the reason for the `{ASC 0232}` solution might be our different keyboard layouts.. mine is German, for example

Answer (score 10):

You can avoid the whole problem if you assign the "unfortunate" hotkey combination to something else.
What I did:

- Go to *Tools->Options->Advanced->Hotkeys*
- Turn on *"Enable keyboard shortcuts*"
- assign <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> to "*Take a snapshot during video calls*"

It was driving me crazy, I found the combined answer on skype forums.